# AS3 my external swf file is overlapping with main swf file

Tags: actionscript-3

i am new to AS3, i have been trying to setup a simple simulation in AS3 for 2 months.
i have pafanbalance1.swf file which just navigate from one scene to other and at the last scene loads a swf file named fescue.swf . it gets loadded easily but pafanbalance1.swf keep on overlapping with the fescue.swf which obviously i want to avoid. please help.
here is link to my .fla file on data hosting site.

http://www.datafilehost.com/d/3396ad6f

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scene 5 add stop in the Actions frame.

```
stop();
// CREATE A NEW LOADER OBJECT TO HOLD THE LOADED CONTENT
var holder:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(holder);
holder.load(new URLRequest("fescue.swf"));;
```

Comment: No problem, glad it worked.  Feel free to select my answer to be correct.